# Using PowerShell to generate report of all AD users with Manager

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Please bear with me. I have no experience using AAD/PS.

I am just playing around trying to generate a list of users and their managers.

What I have done is something like this:

```
$UserId = (Get-AzureADUser -All $true).ObjectId
$bla = foreach ($User in $UserId)
    {
        write-output $User
        Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $User
    }
$bla | Out-File "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
```

I populate $UserId with a users ObjectId and then search manager for that user user the Get-AzureADUserManager.

How can I change it to generate a list that includes the following data:

*UsersObjectId  UserUPN  UserType  ManagersObjectId  ManagerUPN  ManagerUserType*

I also want it to include all UserObjectIds that does not have any manager set (include null).

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$output = @()

$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $manager = Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $user.ObjectId

    $data = New-Object -TypeName psobject

    $data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UsersObjectId -Value $user.ObjectId
    $data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserUPN -Value $user.UserPrincipalName
    $data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserType -Value $user.UserType
    $data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ManagersObjectId -Value $manager.ObjectId
    $data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ManagerUPN -Value $manager.UserPrincipalName
    $data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ManagerUserType -Value $manager.UserType

    $output += $data

}

$output | Export-Csv -Path output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

It will create a CSV file with columns equal to the data you are looking for, where each row represents a user from the original query.

This also works if `Get-AzureADUserManager` returns null.

Comment: Awesome + just had to include $true on the Get-AzureADUser -All and it works like a charm. Now I understand this better and can expand, thanks Shawn!